# Why are my entities not being lazy loaded?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF 6 and defining my database with Code First.

The following line of code returns a Transaction entity, however the EndorsementInfo navigation property is null.  I've checked the database and there is definitely data for the test data. "var trans" does appear to have a valid IQueryable, but navigation property t.EndorsementInfo is null when it shouldn't be.

```
var trans = unitOfWork.GetRepository<Transaction>().GetAll().Where(t => t.PolicyId == command.PolicyId);

results.Transactions = new List<TransactionListItem>();
foreach (var t in trans)
{
    results.Transactions.Add(new TransactionListItem
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        EffDate = t.EffectiveDate,
        EffectiveDate = t.EffectiveDate.ToShortDateString(),
        TransactionType = t.TransactionType.ToStringValue(),
        EndorsementType = t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Endorsement ? 
             t.EndorsementInfo.EndorsementType.Description : ""
    });
}
```

Transaction Entity:

```
public class Transaction : EntityBase
{
    [Required]
    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }

    public long PolicyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Policy Policy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Quote QuoteInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual Cancellation CancellationInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual NewBusiness NewBusinessInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual Endorsement EndorsementInfo { get; set; }        
}
```

Endorsement Entity

```
public class Endorsement : EntityBase
{
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }

    public long EndorsementTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual EndorsementType EndorsementType { get; set; }

    public int EndorsementNum { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string EndorsementDesc { get; set; }

    public Decimal? Premium { get; set; }
}
```

Code First Fluent Configurations

```
public class TransactionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Transaction>
{
    public TransactionConfiguration()
    {
        HasOptional(t => t.QuoteInfo).WithRequired(q => q.Transaction);
        HasOptional(t => t.NewBusinessInfo).WithRequired(q => q.Transaction);
        HasOptional(t => t.EndorsementInfo).WithRequired(q => q.Transaction);
        HasOptional(t => t.CancellationInfo).WithRequired(q => q.Transaction);
    }
}
```

Repositories implementation of GetAll

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll(string include)
{
    return _set.Include(include);
}
```

I've checked and rechecked that everything is set up correctly.  I don't know what I could be missing.

Thanks.

Comment: null exception ? disposed exception ?

Comment: null exception in the foreach. (first block) And the only thing that's null is the EndorsementInfo.

Comment: you set the `EndorsementInfo` as optional, probably the endorsement really doesn't exist in the database, meaning that the `Endorsement_Id` column on `Transaction` table are null..

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This was the first thing that I thought of and checked. But I decided to recheck it because you also went there. That's when I realized that the actual exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' with an inner exception of {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."}.  So now I need to find out what else has a context open when this command is being executed.

Comment: The only other possible open DataReader is from within a line of code directly above my initial block quoted, "var policy = unitOfWork.GetRepository<Policy>().GetById(command.PolicyId);"  GetById implements DbSet.Find.  So, changing my question now ... after I have the data I need from the policy entity, how do I close its DataReader?

Comment: Execute all the data first into memory (to a `List` or a `DataSet`) before executing another data reader with the same connection, I'm not sure the implementation of your repository. Or probably adding `ToArray()` in the end of `Where(t => t.PolicyId == command.PolicyId)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an opened connection to execute two data readers, you need to enable the multiple result set in the connection string.

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

Comment: This worked as a blanket solution. What also worked was making better use of the navigation properties on the first entity, in this case Policy. It had a Transaction ICollection that I wasn't using, but by changing my code I eliminated the need for the second IQueryable. Thanks for your help.